# How to create a drop down list

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to replicate this dropdown list that is on this website (1st image). I've tried using a regular dropdown menu but it comes out very small and it is not centered on the page. How can I create multiple dropdowns in the center of the right side of my split screen? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Open+Sans", sans-serif;
 }

 .navbar {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #0C133C;
 }
 
 
 #nav {
     background-color: #fff; 
     color: white;
     width: 100%;
 
 }
 .nav {
   float: right;
     text-align: left;
   margin: 0;
 }
 .nav > li {                                                             
     display:Inline-block;
     padding: 20px 50px 10px 9px;                              
 }
 
.nav > li a {                                               
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0C133C;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;

}
.clearer {
    clear:both;
}

  
}
.subnav class{
  margin: 0;
position:relative;
}

 .subnav > div a {                                               
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #0C133C;
     font-size: 18px;
padding: 20px 30px 10px 9px;
}
  
.logo {
margin-top: 1rem;
}

.subnav {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
margin-right: 1rem; 

}

.split {
  height: 70%;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -50;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
  background-color: #282C41;
color: white;
margin-top: .5rem;
 font-size: 15px;

}
 
.right {
  right: 0;
  background-color: #CDCDCD;
margin-top: .5rem;
font-size: 18px;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Navbar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"
    

</head>

<body>

<div class="navbar">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Sign In</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clearer"></div>
        </div>
        

<subnav class="subnav subnav-light bg-light">
<img src="universallogo.jpg" class="logo"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
<a class="subnav=brand" href="#">
 <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Bonds</a>
</a>
 <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Report a Claim</a>
 <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">About Us</a>
<a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Search</a>
</div>
</subnav>
 
</ul>

<div class="split left">
  <div class="centered">
    <h1>GET YOUR LICENSE & PERMIT BONDS FAST & EASY</h1>
    <p>We provide our Customers with a fast, easy, and secure way to get bonded. Get your Free Quote in minutes.
</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="split right">
 <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Select Your State
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">California</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Illinois</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Michigan</a></li>
 <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ohio</a></li>
  </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>




</body>
```

[image: 1st Image, the example I would like to replicate]
[image: 2nd Image, what I currently have]

Answer (score 1):

HTML has an `<option>` tag that is standardized selection inputs.

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Open+Sans", sans-serif;
 }

 .navbar {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #0C133C;
 }
 
 
 #nav {
     background-color: #fff; 
     color: white;
     width: 100%;
 
 }
 .nav {
   float: right;
     text-align: left;
   margin: 0;
 }
 .nav > li {                                                             
     display:Inline-block;
     padding: 20px 50px 10px 9px;                              
 }
 
.nav > li a {                                               
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0C133C;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;

}
.clearer {
    clear:both;
}

  
}
.subnav class{
  margin: 0;
position:relative;
}

 .subnav > div a {                                               
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #0C133C;
     font-size: 18px;
padding: 20px 30px 10px 9px;
}
  
.logo {
margin-top: 1rem;
}

.subnav {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
margin-right: 1rem; 

}

.split {
  height: 70%;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -50;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
  background-color: #282C41;
color: white;
margin-top: .5rem;
 font-size: 15px;

}
 
.right {
  right: 0;
  background-color: #CDCDCD;
margin-top: .5rem;
font-size: 18px;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;

}

select {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Navbar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    

</head>

<body>

<div class="navbar">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Sign In</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clearer"></div>
        </div>
        

<subnav class="subnav subnav-light bg-light">
<img src="universallogo.jpg" class="logo"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
<a class="subnav=brand" href="#">
 <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Bonds</a>
</a>
 <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Report a Claim</a>
 <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">About Us</a>
<a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Search</a>
</div>
</subnav>

<div class="split left">
  <div class="centered">
    <h1>GET YOUR LICENSE & PERMIT BONDS FAST & EASY</h1>
    <p>We provide our Customers with a fast, easy, and secure way to get bonded. Get your Free Quote in minutes.
</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="split right">
  <select id="state">
    <option disabled selected>Select Your State</option>
    <option value="california">California</option>
    <option value="illinois">Illinois</option>
    <option value="michigan">Michigan</option>
    <option value="ohio">Ohio</option>
  </select>
</div>




</body>
```

And to get the selected value, check the `value` property of the `<select>` element, e.g.: `document.getElementById("state").value`;

Stylize your `<select>` element to specify width, margin, padding, etc, e.g.: `select { width: 100%; }`

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select